# Ajax Html Form Submission Not Working

Tags: jquery

Am trying to submit the HTML form bellow with AJAX to the search page and bring results in the index page where i made my search we out refresh the index page, therefore i try to code some AJAX to do this for me but it seems the form can't be submitted can one help me solve this problem? when i look on the URL it shows the q has no value, any suggestion or already made code is also greatly appreciated.

The code which is failing to submit the form.

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery9min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  $('#search_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url:"search.php?q="+$('#search').val(),
      success: function (html) {
        $("#search_results").html(html);
      }
    });
</script>

<form style="width:230px; margin:0 auto;" id="find" name="explore">
  <input type="image" src="images/searchthis.png" id="search_btn">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="q" placeHolder="type to start searching">
</form>

<div id="search_results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the url that is ok and also be sure that $('#search').val() has something, because if is '' you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#search_btn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var search = $('#search').val();
   $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url:"search.php?q="+ search,
      success: function (html) {
        $("#search_results").html(html);
      }
});
```

Comment: Q now has value but no results on the DIV

Comment: What do you get with just an alert(html) inside the success callback?